# I get empty fields, even though there is data there

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

```
SELECT 
 [Structure]=mpc.StructureName
 ,[Type]=CASE pcbor.TypeId 
             WHEN '0080' THEN 'type1'
             WHEN '1845' THEN 'type2'
             WHEN '0125' THEN 'type3'
             Else 'N/A' END
 ,Type_De=CASE pcde.TypeId WHEN '0040' THEN 'Type99' Else 'N/A' END 
 ,Type_Ee=CASE pcee.TypeId WHEN '1525' THEN 'Type98'
                           WHEN '1530' THEN 'Type97' Else 'N/A' END
 ,Type_Lt=CASE pclt.TypeId WHEN '1525' THEN 'Type96'
                           WHEN '1530' THEN 'Type95' Else 'N/A' END

FROM [static].[MPC] with (nolock)
     JOIN [static].[MPCCenter] mpcpc with (nolock) ON mpcpc.MPCId = mpc.MPCId
     JOIN [static].[ProCenter] pc with (nolock) ON pc.ProCenterId = mpcpc.ProCenterId
    LEFT JOIN [static].TypeBor pcbor with (nolock) ON pcbor.ProCenterId = pc.ProCenterId
    LEFT JOIN [static].Type_De pcde with (nolock) ON pcde.ProCenterId = pc.ProCenterId
    LEFT JOIN [static].Type_Ee pcee with (nolock) ON pcee.ProCenterId = pc.ProCenterId
    LEFT JOIN [static].Type_Lt pclt with (nolock) ON pclt.ProCenterId = pc.ProCenterId
```

Is there anything wrong with my code, because there is data in all the tables but all I get in my result is data from the first table(pcbor.typeid) the rest is N/A ?

Comment: Syntactically I see nothing wrong - try taking out joins one at a time (starting from the end) and see if that uncovers your issue.  Also start by taking out the CASE statements (just showing `XXX.TypeID` to make sure the data there is what you expect.

Comment: remove joins one by one and check with of it is causing no to return data

Comment: Try setting up a SQL Fiddle.  If your code runs, there's not much we can do on this end other than say that the values are not in the data.  I would check your `join` conditions, but you do not provide enough information even for speculation.

Comment: I'm assuming that as you say you're getting blank fields, you're getting rows returned, but the data appears blank.. can you try removing [structure]= and [type]= (or just specify * in the select statement).  Also it's a good idea to be specific in your joins.. is 'JOIN' an 'INNER JOIN' ?

Comment: You are correct that there is something wrong with the joins, because when I do 

FROM [static].[MPC] with (nolock)
     RIGHT JOIN [static].[MPCCenter] mpcpc with (nolock) ON mpcpc.MPCId = mpc.MPCId
    RIGHT JOIN [static].[ProCenter] pc with (nolock) ON pc.ProCenterId = mpcpc.ProCenterId
    INNER JOIN [static].Type_De pcde with (nolock) ON pcde.ProCenterId = pc.ProCenterId

I get the correct number of rows with Type99

Comment: Not an answer to your question but why all the nolock hints? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate data? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You are applying left join and you are also not checking Isnull as it may possible to give null values due to left join and 'N/A' will be there, you are left joining 3 different tables which returns different rows for each ProcenterId, so 'N/A' would be there

see the below attach image (what i understood from your scenario).

[image]